# passing a model into a directive in AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-formly

I've got 4 select drop-downs on a page.  Below each one I would like dynamic HTML to generate based on the selection using angular-formly.

I have this so far:

**ruleSelect.js.erb**

```
angular.module('productsApp')
  .directive('ruleSelect', [
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace:  false,
      // require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
        options: '=',
        ruleBldr: '='
      },
      templateUrl: "<%= asset_path('shared/templates/ruleSelect.html') %>",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      }
    };
 }]);
```

**ruleSelect.html.slim**

```
select.form-control ng-model="value"
  option ng-repeat="field in options | fieldFilter:['templateOptions', 'label']" value="{{$index+1}}"
    | {{field.templateOptions.label}}

form
  formly-form fields="ruleBldr.form[value].fieldGroup"
```

But on the scope `options` is set but `ruleBldr` is empty.

**HTML page**

```
.row
  .col-md-offset-6.col-md-6 ng-repeat="obj in ruleB.formObjects"
    label.control-label () {{obj.fieldGroup[0].template}}
    rule-select options='obj.fieldGroup' ruleBldr="obj"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` in `ruleB.form[value]` isn't defined anywhere.

If the form is supposed to be created based on the value selected in the `<select>` you need to add `ng-model` to `<select>`. Note that `ng-model` should always be an object.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
   scope.selectModel ={}
}

select.form-control ng-model="selectModel.value"

formly-form fields="ruleBldr.form[selectModel.value].fieldGroup"
```

Some of this is a bit of a guess since problem description is very poor. Also I don't know the proper html syntax for your template system

I'm also not sure if you need the initial value passed into directive from controller

Comment: But ruleBldr has the correct keys but all the values are blank.

Comment: having a very hard time following what the exact problem is. Create a demo that replicates this

Comment: also `ruleBldr="obj"` should be `rule-bldr="obj"` in the html. One good trick is `<pre>{{ruleBldr.form | json}}</pre>` in the view to see what a scope object looks like